# Background Worker Running Twice on bw_DoWork() and bw_ProgressChanged() when using textBox1.AppendText()

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I can't figure out why the `bw_ProgressChanged()` runs twice when I use the `textBox1.AppendText()`.  Also the `bw_DoWork()` runs twice.

The code is just a copy paste from the [Microsoft example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) with the difference that I'm using `textBox1.AppendText()` instead of `textBox1.Text = ""`.

The code looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
        {
            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                worker.ReportProgress((i * 10));
            }
        }
    }

    private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.AppendText(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%\n");
    }

    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Cancelled == true))
        {
            this.textBox1.AppendText("Canceled!");
        }

        else if (!(e.Error == null))
        {
            this.textBox1.AppendText("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
        }

        else
        {
            this.textBox1.AppendText("Done!");
        }
    }
}
```

The **textbox1 text** looks like this:

```
10%
10%
20%
20%
30%
30%
40%
40%
50%
50%
60%
60%
70%
70%
80%
80%
90%
90%
100%
100%
10%
10%
20%
20%
30%
30%
40%
40%
50%
50%
60%
60%
70%
70%
80%
80%
90%
90%
100%
100%
Done!Done!
```

Instead of:

```
10%
20%
30%
40%
50%
60%
70%
80%
90%
100%
Done!
```

I have tried to pass the progress directly to a local variable and then pass it to the `textbox1` but it doesn't make any difference.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside the event method runs twice because you've somehow subscribed to the `ProgressChanged` event twice.

Since I don't see two subscriptions in your code, you've probably subscribed to it through the designer (check the `Designer.cs` file to confirm), so remove this line from the constructor:

```
bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
```

While you're at it, double-check `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted` too. You're most likely subscribing to those twice as well, which would explain why your output is printing 10 through 100, and then printing the same doubled-up values again.